# Building large scale REST service - PHPFog, cloudControl, Orchestra or Amazon AWS

Tags: php, rest, cloud, scalability

I am about to plan and build a large scale REST service. Because of that I have looked into how I could make my setup in the cloud. At first I wanted to do it with Amazon RDS and Amazon EC2 - however I then looked into the various PHP cloud platform services (PHPFog, cloudControl, Orchestra) which looks like exactly what I want.

However I do have some questions regarding this:

- What is the overall difference between the three services? (PHPFog, cloudControl and Orchestra)
- I want a platform that can scale automatically at peak hours, meaning that I should not have to pay for the resources needed at peak hours all day. As to what I have read, PHPFog do not support elastic scaling?
- How well does these perform? Could big services like Twitter, facebook etc. run on these platforms?
- Does these services support backups?
- Anything else I should think of when choosing one of these platforms? Or perhaps should I not choose one of these?

Comment: You might want to look at some other options as well. Something between PaaS and pure EC2: Cloud management services like Scalr.net, or Rightscale. They make it easier to manage your infrastructure but you still maintain some more control than with PaaS. Maybe a nice compromise between the 2 types of solutions.

Comment: @webgr: Thanks for the comment mate! I will definitely check this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PaaS Hosting is relativly new. I think no vendor is longer than 2 years out of Beta. The scene changes rapidly, more and more Startups are entering the market. And it's hard to compare them, each has it's own unique style and pricing model.

Shameless Plug: We (***• fortrabbit***) are also developing a PHP PaaS for Europe. That's why we know so much about the others ;) We have just written a PHP PaaS Comparsion. 11 providers – a snapshot of the current situation:

- http://blog.fortrabbit.com/comparing-cloud-hosting-platforms/

**Tips for choosing the right PaaS**

- Test the service, there is always a free plan
- Choose a vendor in your country (billing, legal aspects and SPEED)
- Consider if you want a CLI or a GUI

Answer (score 2):

(1) I can't speak for PHPFog or cloudControl but I can tell you a bit about Engine Yard’s Orchestra platform.

- **Stack:** We use nginx 1.1.x and PHP 5.3.9. We use nginx for our caching layer and load balancer also. Writing to the filesystem is discouraged so that apps are stateless and can be easily replicated and distributed allowing you to scale horizontally.
- **Deployment:** Git or SVN. Once you deploy your application Orchestra will check your repo every 60 seconds and automatically pull down any changes. You only need to worry about pushing changes to your repo.
- **Billing:** We bill hourly. When you deploy an application we bill you for hourly usage so you only pay for what you use.
- **Support:** Olark Live Chat, Tender app ticket support (ZenDesk soon), IRC, Twitter, E-Mail + on-boarding support (called PANDA)
- **Scaling:** Your application can automatically scale up and down to accommodate for traffic spikes and increased load.

(2) Orchestra supports auto-scaling apps. A load balancer sits in front of your elastic app and distributes the workload across all the instances associated with the app. If your app experiences a traffic spike, we will add scale units until the requests can be met. Once the traffic subsides, your app will scale back down again. See our blog post about elastic for more details:

http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2012/orchestra-elastic-apps-for-everyone/

(3) You can run smalls and large apps on Orchestra. If your app is stateless and can scale horizontally, we can scale out it for you indefinitely. See our docs on system constraints for more info on how to build stateless apps:

http://docs.orchestra.io/kb/system-constraints/system-constraints

As you get bigger, you will no doubt want to run additional services along side your app. Things as big as Twitter or Facebook are usually comprised a collection of different apps and services. We offer some additional services via our addons, and we will continue to add more. Let me know if there’s anything else you’d like to see!

(4) Orchestra does hourly backups of the MySQL server. Internally, we backup our user-configuration, load-balancer configurations, and user-settings every 3 hours. The code is pulled from your repository, so we do not make backups of that.

Answer (score 1):

1. While they are all PaaS for PHP, it might be easy to start doing an apples-to-apples comparison based on feature set and pricing. You can do this fairly easily on your own, so I'll focus on some of the less obvious things to consider as well.

   - Ecosystem: With PHP Fog we have the benefit of having 10s of thousands of applications running on our platform and we are growing faster every day. This means it is proven as a platform. It also means you get the benefit of having other customers to help you out on the discussion forums, writing tutorials, etc.
   - Support: we have three dedicated support engineers. You will get useful responses to open issues very quickly. If you need it, they can dive in and help with your code. If you have special case requests, they can handle that too.
   - Big customers: In addition to having a large ecosystem, we also have large customers. Some customers have around a million hits a day. We have others with even more.
2. PHP Fog is adding support for scheduled and responsive scaling; however, in the mean time you can scale with the slider. We're also releasing an API and command line tool VERY soon, so you'll be able to setup automatic scaling yourself too. It's very easy.
3. We have applications hosted on PHP Fog which serve over a million requests a day and they run without any problems and with room to grow. I already mentioned our awesome support team that can help you in building the application such that it is ready for a PaaS environment.
4. The entire PHP Fog platform has redundancy, failover, and backups built into every piece of the stack. This includes the load balancers, Varnish cache server, application servers, database servers, git repositories.
5. Yes, you should consider other PaaS players which aren't specific to PHP. AppFog supports a variety of languages (PHP, Ruby, etc). It also supports database technologies like MySQL, MongoDB, Redis, etc. If you stick to the PHP/MySQL stack, you might not need this. However, if you do need to add other services in the future, this will be much easier.